# POST variable empty

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have the following controller file:

```
<?php
class Test extends CI_Controller 
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();  
    }

    function index()
    {   
        print_r($_POST);
        $view_params = array();

        $this->load->view('test', $view_params);
    }
}
?>
```

with a view file of:

```
<form action="/test" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="test" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>

<ul id="account">
    <li class="separator url"><label>Domain Address (URL)</label><input maxlength="22" type="text" name="sub_url" />
    <small class="subtext">This is the link people use to find your site. You can change this at any time.</small>
</li>
</ul>
<img class="green_arrow" src="assets/images/green_arrow.png" />
```

When I hit the submit button, no post data is being spit out, but when I do a page refresh, it says data has been posted and will resend it.

Also, I think that html is just a snippet, but please understand that I am trying to reduce code and therefore reduce the number of problem areas. The reason where there is so much garbage after that is because if I remove that the view file ceases to work, but that's another question.

Comment: You don't need your constructor there if you're just calling the parent's constructor - that's done for you already.

Comment: What does it print exactly? Array()? Or nothing at all?

Comment: Thanks Jacob, I didn't know that I didn't need the constructor. That'll help reduce my code from now on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CodeIgniter empties $_POST, $_GET etc. for security purposes. Use the Input class instead.

```
$post = $this->input->post();
```

or

```
$some_data = $this->input->post('some_data');
```

Have a read here:
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html

Answer (score 1):

Hey Johnathan, I'm glad I got to fix your problem. All you had to do was enable apache's mod rewrite.

```
a2enmod rewrite 
/etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```

Because you didn't have apache's mod rewrite, code igniter must have screwed up some rewrite rules and messed up your form data on post back.